# jquery not triggered in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an internal Javascript app and it has a function for creating editable lists of objects. It loops through an array of objects, and displays a summary for each one along with an edit button. It then displays some more buttons at the bottom of the list for creating new items and going to the previous screen.

All of the buttons work, expect ones created within the loop. The click event never fires for the buttons added to the DOM within the loop. The really strange thing is that if I take the edit variable and append to the DOM outside of the loop the click event does fire.

```
var displayArray = function (where, list, summarise, display, newItem, completion, back) {
    var listing = $("<div>");
    listing.addClass("Listing");

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var index = i;
        var edit = createButton("Edit", function () {
            display(list[index]);
        });

        var anchor = $("<p>");
        anchor.text(summarise(list[index]));
        anchor.append(edit); //this will create an edit button, but the click event is never fired
        listing.append(anchor);
    }
    where.append(listing);

    var create = createButton("New", newItem);

    where.empty();
    where.append(listing);
    where.append(create);
    //where.append(edit); // uncomment this and it will create a button that will display the last item in the list
    if (back) { where.append(createButton("Back", back)); }

    if (completion) {
        completion();
    }
}

var createButton = function(name, action){
    var button = $("<input>");
    button.attr("type", "button");
    button.attr("value", name);
    button.on("click", action);
    return button;
}
```

The variables being passed into the function are as follows:

- where = the html element that will display the items
- list = the array of objects to display
- summarise = a function that generates summary text for an object passed to it that will be displayed for this object listing
- display = a function that generates the edit screen for an object
- newItem = a function that generates a new object and displays the edit screen for it
- completion = a function to call after the screen has been built that will generate any additional UI as needed.
- back = a function to display the previous screen

The behaviour is consistent across IE9, Firefox 20.0.1, and Chrome 29.0.1547.66

Comment: it looks like a problem with not using event delegation....

Comment: how is the event handlers added to the button... is it added before the loop is executed if so is it using event delegation

Comment: It seems like a common problem with `index`. Remember that JS doesn't have scope in for loops. Try surrounding your Edit handler with a function and pass in the index. The code for that would probably look prettier with event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what the problem is here:

Try this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var index = i;
    var edit = createButton("Edit", (function (item) {
        return function () {
            display(item);
        };
    })(list[index]));
```

Comment: I think that is going to have the same effect. You'd need to move the `var index` line inside the `"Edit", (function ()`. That'll work too.